# Why did you ask me if they have any allergies?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, backshifting

In this sentence, the person is referring to a question that was asked in the past but a condition that is current. Can the past and present tense be used in this case or should it be "Why did you ask me if they had any allergies?"

Comment: Both present and past can be used here.

Comment: If the the question was asked in 1970, you obviously have to use a past tense.

Comment: Both are okay; the "backshift" is optional.

Comment: Both are grammatical; the 'backshift' is optional unless, as Centaurus says, there is a compelling reason to backshift ('they' have all since died; there was a long time between the possibility of their having allergies (think 'the British at Waterloo') and the question; the question itself was many years ago (1970)).